# MongoDB Aggregate sum with lookup to another collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

There are 2 schemas. One is a CostCode and the other is a Timesheet. Each timesheet is associated to one or more cost codes. The Timesheet has a costCodes array and each item in this array contains a reference to a CostCode and hoursWorked. The result desired is to have a list of all CostCode documents where each doc includes a sum of hoursWorked from the Timesheets.

**CostCode Schema:**

```
{
  label: { type: String, required: false },
  description: { type: String }
  budgetedHours: { type: Number, required: false },
}
```

**Timesheet Schema:**

```
costCodes: [{
  costCode: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'CostCode' },
  percentage: { type: Number },
  hoursWorked: { type: Number },
}],
startDateTimeUTC: { type: Date, required: true },
endDateTimeUTC: { type: Date },
```

**Desired Result:**

```
{
  _id: "6447dedc26faeedd35b62c0c"
  label: "Cost Code 1"
  description: ""
  budgetedHours: 100
  totalHoursWorked: 53
},
{
  _id: "6445e11b27d9bbb7779bb89b"
  label: "Cost Code 2"
  description: ""
  budgetedHours: 150
  totalHoursWorked: 42
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option is to write an aggregation pipeline on the CostCode collection.

1. first `$lookup` on TimeSheet collection based on the `_id` of CostCode and `costCodes.costCode` of TimeSheet
2. `$unwind` twice to get separate documents
3. filter out using `$match` the docs where the `_id` is equal to `timesheets.costCodes.costCode`
4. Finally `$group` and sum the `timesheets.costCodes.hoursWorked` fields to get the `totalHoursWorked`

here is a [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pAQqObcFdZL). on top of the playground there is a Stage dropdown where you can look at the intermediate stages of the pipeline.

```js
db.costcode.aggregate([
  { $lookup: { from: "timesheet", localField: "_id", foreignField: "costCodes.costCode", as: "timesheets" } },
  { $unwind: "$timesheets" },
  { $unwind: "$timesheets.costCodes" },
  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$timesheets.costCodes.costCode", "$_id" ] } } },
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", label: { $first: "$label" }, description: { $first: "$description" }, budgetedHours: { $first: "$budgetedHours" }, totalHoursWorked: { $sum: "$timesheets.costCodes.hoursWorked" } } }
])
```

Comment: Wow! This is fantastic and explained very clearly. Thank you, @cmgchess! One thing missing is if a cost code is not associated to any timesheets, that it still be displayed, but with totalHoursWorked = 0. I added a 3rd cost code to your playground example... how can we display this unused cost code as well? Thank you! https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vyu1ohFU7JU

Comment: So basically I used preservenulls when unwinding and in the match I didn't remove if there is no timesheets

Comment: after taking a closer look at your latest mongoplayground link, the totalHoursWorked are no longer accurate. For timesheets that have multiple costcodes associated, it appears to be summing hoursWorked from all of them. How can we fix this? Thank you.

Comment: @JamesEisenlohr you are correct! i missed it can you check https://mongoplayground.net/p/2VmqmCefmYn or https://mongoplayground.net/p/maSsei7bFcd

Comment: that definitely fixed it! You have been so helpful! Thank you. :)